# Declaring ViewModel in two approaches

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Reading [knockoutJs tutorial](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and couldn't make this to work. On the first page, the first approach was used and on the second page the second approach was used to create a model. But the second approach was not working. What could be the problem?

**First Approach**

```
var AppViewModel {
    this.firstName = 'Bob',
    this.lastName = 'Smith'
};
```

**Second Approach**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = 'Bob';
    this.lastName = 'Smith';
}
```

Html portion is below:

```
<body>

  <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>



  <script type="text/javascript">
      ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
  </script>
</body>
```

This works for the first approach but the second approach throws error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError:
>   firstName is not defined; Bindings value: text: firstName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first approach you defined an object. In the second approach you defined a class' constructor so you have to create an instance of the class using `new` keyword:

```
<body>
  <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The first was an anonymous object and the second is a class that needs an instance to make it work. I see your point